# node.js read string with 7 bit encoded int length

Tags: node.js

I get data from C# tcp server which sent me string. The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.

How I can parse length in node.js

Comment: It's slightly unclear. Can you please give an example. What length is this for? Does the string contain the length in binary or denary? Is the length using a fixed number of bits for it's representation or is it variable?

Comment: Give an example value that you get, and what you want to be able to figure out from it. That would make what you're wanting much easier to help with. Right now it sounds like you're trying to ask how to decode some encoded string that we don't have the rules for how it was encoded. Javascript has binary operators and binary literals (if you're on a current-ish node) so you can convert the string to bytes and do what needs done if you really need to decode it.

Comment: idk why my C# tags deleted, I need something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring(v=vs.110).aspx C# write string with: length(7-bit encoded integer)+string and I need read this string from Buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
function ReadSharpString(buffer)
{
    let length = 0, shift = 0, offset = 0;
    let byte;

    do
    {
        byte = buffer[offset++];
        length |= (byte & 0x7F) << shift;
        shift += 7;
    }
    while (byte >= 0x80);

    this.length = () => {
        return length;
    };

    this.toBuffer = () => {
        return buffer.slice(offset, offset + length)
    };

    this.toString = () => {
        return this.toBuffer().toString()
    };
}
```

Example:

let string = new ReadSharpString(new Buffer([9, 87, 45, 68, 45, 87, 45, 87, 45, 87]));

console.log(string.toBuffer());

console.log(string.toString());

console.log(string.length());

Comment: I understand you have an implemetation of "sevenBitEncodingToInt" that allows you to read the length of a string. Maybe you have an implementation for a reverse function that writes int to 7 bit encoding into binary buffer instead?